# Redirect to site if WWW part is missing

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

After viewing answer of almost a same question on SO i added this line in .htaccess

`RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]`
`RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]`

But it did not worked for these 2 cases

example.com
example.com/
example.com/index.php

In other cases it successful redirected to the www.example.com/...
What is wrong in my .htaccess ?

`Additional Info`
For some kind of unknown reason [to me at least] i can not enable ERROR page for PHP, but works fine for HTML only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly this is a dns issue. Try adding a cname record:

CNAME yourdomain.com www.yourdomain.com

Comment: You need to login to your domain hosting control panel and find the dns settings. If you are in doubt, contact your host and ask them if they'll do it for you. @Sourav