# redirect to site if www part is missing using PHP

Tags: php, redirect

I asked the same question [Redirect to site if WWW part is missing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6785310) but the answer did not helped in my case, as i was unable to get to change the CNAME and .htaccess also failed.
The only option left is to use PHP.
Can anyone help me ?

If someone tries to browse example.com or example.com/ or so the PHP will redirect it to www.example.com/..

`edit`

```
SetEnv TZ Asia/Calcutta 

ErrorDocument 400 /error.html
ErrorDocument 401 /error.html
ErrorDocument 403 /error.html
ErrorDocument 404 /error.html

<ifModule mod_php4.c>
 php_value zlib.output_compression 16386
</ifModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^home$ home.php [L]

RewriteRule ^credit$ credits.php [L]
RewriteRule ^credits$ credits.php [L]

RewriteRule ^profile/(\d+)/?$ profile.php?id=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^user/(\d+)/?$ view_profile.php?id=$1 [L]

RewriteRule ^blog/?$ blog.php [L]
RewriteRule ^blog/(\d+)/?$ blog.php?id=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^blog.php/(\d+)/?$ blog.php?id=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^blog/(\d+)/([A-Za-z0-9-_\[\]]+)/?$ blog.php?id=$1&title=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^blog.php/(\d+)/([A-Za-z0-9-_\[\]]+)/?$ blog.php?id=$1&title=$2 [L]

RewriteRule ^blogbyauthor.php/(\d+)/?$ blogbyauthor.php?uid=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^blogbyauthor/(\d+)/?$ blogbyauthor.php?uid=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^blogbyauthor/(\d+)/?$ blogbyauthor.php?uid=$1 [L]

RewriteRule ^blog_by_category.php/([A-Za-z0-9-_\[\]]+)/?$ blog_by_category.php?category=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^blog_by_category/([A-Za-z0-9-_\[\]]+)/?$ blog_by_category.php?category=$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: 'www' in front of links sucks.... :( Don't!

Comment: @daGrevis: yes it does :/ I see no reason to use it :/

Comment: I would recommend that you try and figure out why/what 'failed' about the .htaccess as this is pretty much the best, and simplest way to redirect correctly to your domain whilst including www.

Comment: @daGrevis this is your opinion. I share it though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this in .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymlinks
    RewriteEngine on

    # site.com -> www.site.com
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^site.com
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.site.com/$1 [R=301,L]

</IfModule>
```

Obviously you should change `site.com` with your domain.

---

**Update**: incorporated your code with my suggestion.

```
SetEnv TZ Asia/Calcutta 

ErrorDocument 400 /error.html
ErrorDocument 401 /error.html
ErrorDocument 403 /error.html
ErrorDocument 404 /error.html

<ifModule mod_php4.c>
 php_value zlib.output_compression 16386
</ifModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

# site.com -> www.site.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^site.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.site.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^home$ home.php [L]

RewriteRule ^credit$ credits.php [L]
RewriteRule ^credits$ credits.php [L]

RewriteRule ^profile/(\d+)/?$ profile.php?id=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^user/(\d+)/?$ view_profile.php?id=$1 [L]

RewriteRule ^blog/?$ blog.php [L]
RewriteRule ^blog/(\d+)/?$ blog.php?id=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^blog.php/(\d+)/?$ blog.php?id=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^blog/(\d+)/([A-Za-z0-9-_\[\]]+)/?$ blog.php?id=$1&title=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^blog.php/(\d+)/([A-Za-z0-9-_\[\]]+)/?$ blog.php?id=$1&title=$2 [L]

RewriteRule ^blogbyauthor.php/(\d+)/?$ blogbyauthor.php?uid=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^blogbyauthor/(\d+)/?$ blogbyauthor.php?uid=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^blogbyauthor/(\d+)/?$ blogbyauthor.php?uid=$1 [L]

RewriteRule ^blog_by_category.php/([A-Za-z0-9-_\[\]]+)/?$ blog_by_category.php?category=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^blog_by_category/([A-Za-z0-9-_\[\]]+)/?$ blog_by_category.php?category=$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: I am wondering why the downvote? The answer solves an issue here, whether we like it or not is a completely different issue.

Comment: Sorry shef. In first minute OP was requesting Php, there was "I don't want to rely on .htaccess" and I didn't spot his edit. However, this is question with tag php, not .htaccess

Comment: Sure it's tagged PHP, but the OP also stated that the htaccess failed. So, I suggested an htaccess solution, which will work, because PHP will be a huge overhead.

Comment: Not what the OP requested obviously, but if that does it this is by far a better solution, +1

Comment: @Sourav: Do you have anything else in your .htaccess file? If yes, please share it with us, or at least if you can, explain to us what the code you have is doing.

Comment: @Sourav: Updated my answer. Copy & Paste the code, but don't forget to change `site.com` everywhere with your domain name.

Answer (score 2):

```
$protocol = (@$_SERVER["HTTPS"] == "on") ? "https://" : "http://";

if (substr($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], 0, 4) !== 'www.') {
    header('Location: '.$protocol.'www.'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'/'.$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
    exit;
}
```

Comment: A very minor thing, but I'd change that == to === aswell as the != to !==. A stricter check is slightly faster and more correct.

Comment: I can smell recursion problems for noobs. xD

Answer (score 0):

another (very similiar to genesis) php solution is ..

```
$s = empty($_SERVER["HTTPS"]) ? '' : ($_SERVER["HTTPS"] == "on") ? "s" : "";
$protocol = substr(strtolower($_SERVER["SERVER_PROTOCOL"]), 0, strpos($_SERVER["SERVER_PROTOCOL"], "/")).$s.'://';
$domain = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];

$mypath  = $protocol.$domain;

if($mypath == 'http://yourdomain.com') {
    $uri = '';
    if(isset($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])) {
        $uri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];        
    }
    header ('HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently');
    header ('Location: http://www.yourdomain.com'.$uri);
    exit;
}
```

I hope this helps.